# Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 29 path

Tags: java, android, json

I am getting the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was
>   BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 29 path $.entree[0].photo

It makes no sense to me because my json response should be constructed as follows:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Entree {
    @SerializedName("id")
    public int id;
    @SerializedName("photo")
    public Entree.Photo photo;

    public class Photo {
        @SerializedName("url")
        public String url;
        @SerializedName("web")
        public Entree.Photo.Web web;
        @SerializedName("mobile")
        public Entree.Photo.Mobile mobile;

        public class Web {
            @SerializedName("url")
            public String url;
        }

        public class Mobile {
            @SerializedName("url")
            public String url;
        }
    }
}
```

JSON data:

```
"entrees": [   
  {
    "id": 32,
    "photo": 
     {
       "url": "4c312e9aed37a59319096a03_1.jpg",
       "web": {
          "url": "web_4c312e9aed37a59319096a03_1.jpg"
        },
        "mobile": {
           "url": "mobile_4c312e9aed37a59319096a03_1.jpg"
        }
      }   
    },   
  ...
```

Do you see how Photo is an object and not a string in my class? What am I doing wrong then?

Comment: Are you using any kind of library to make api call ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try mark the inner class with `static`

In [Gson document](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Nested-Classes-including-Inner-Classes-) , it says

> Gson can also deserialize static nested classes. However, Gson can not
>   automatically deserialize the pure inner classes since their no-args
>   constructor also need a reference to the containing Object which is
>   not available at the time of deserialization. You can address this
>   problem by either making the inner class static or by providing a
>   custom InstanceCreator for it.

Comment: Thankss @Garywzh you saved my hours. And can you explain this in detail. Coz i still have some doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your

> GSON Serializable class is not correct,
>   For a JSON response like this,

```
  {
    "entrees": [{
    "id": 32,
    "photo": {
        "url": "4c312e9aed37a59319096a03_1.jpg",
        "web": {
            "url": "web_4c312e9aed37a59319096a03_1.jpg"
        },
        "mobile": {
            "url": "mobile_4c312e9aed37a59319096a03_1.jpg"
        }
    }
}]
   }
```

The GSON class will be as,

```
  public class Entree {
@com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("entrees")
public List<Entrees> Entrees;

public static class Web {
    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("url")
    public String Url;
}

public static class Mobile {
    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("url")
    public String Url;
}

public static class Photo {
    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("url")
    public String Url;
    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("web")
    public Web Web;
    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("mobile")
    public Mobile Mobile;
}

public static class Entrees {
    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("id")
    public int Id;
    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("photo")
    public Photo Photo;
}
}
```